# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "147j"

Tags: java, linux, video-streaming, red5

i was trying to install red5 on redhat.
i followed the procedure from 
http://www.itwebsupport.com/blog/red5-flash-media-server-installation-on-centos-fedora-redhat-rhel

when i try to run the red5 server by following command
cd /usr/local/red5
./red5.sh

it shows following error:

```
Running on  Linux
Starting Red5
Red5 root: /usr/local/red5
Configuation root: /usr/local/red5/conf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "147j"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:570)
    at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.scrubURLList(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:524)
    at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:179)
    at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:97)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:126)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
```

just to inform you its amazon ec2 server.

can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
Integer.parseInt("147j");
```

and `147j` can't be parsed as Integer So you are getting `NumberFormatException`.